# I dont how to use "path" in app.use(). It gives me a result that I was not expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new in express.js and I want to know how to use "path" in app.use() excatly. When I try the code which is following, I get a result but I am so confusing. Can you explain why the result is like that. Thank you so much.

My code is following:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router()
const app  = express();
const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log("Running");
})

app.use("/test",router)
// app.use()


router.get("/test",(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log("test 1");
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    next()
})


router.get("/",(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log("first /");
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    next()
})
router.get("/test",(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log("test 2");
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    next()
})

router.get("/",(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log("second /");
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    next()
})
```

And, I did test in "http://localhost:3000/test" but the result is not as I expected. Console output is :

```
first /
/test
second /
/test
```

But I was expected that result will be

```
test 1
/test
test 2
/test
```

Why is it like that? Could you explain to me? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A request in express passes from top to bottom through your route handlers looking for a match until it finds one, is returned as a response or an error is thrown.

When you mounted your router at:

```js
app.use("/test",router)
```

Express will match requests to `http://localhost:3000/test` and route them to the handlers defined in `router`. However, what you need to understand is that all of the routes in your `router` implicitly begin with `/test`.

To illustate:

```js
router.get("/test",(req,res,next)
// http://localhost:3000/test/test

router.get("/",(req,res,next)
// http://localhost:3000/test
```

When you issued a `GET` request to `http://localhost:3000/test` this is what happened:

1. This matched your request:

```js
app.use("/test",router)
```

2. The request was routed here:

```js
router.get("/",(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log("first /");
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    next()
})
```

3. You called `next()` middleware as opposed to returning a response so this matched:

```js
router.get("/",(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log("second /");
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    next()
})
```

4. You called `next()` middleware again as opposed to returning a response so now your browser hangs waiting for a response and eventually timeouts.

If you go ahead an issue a `GET` request to `http://localhost:3000/test/test` you will get:

```html
test 1
/test/test
test 2
/test/test
```

Comment: right for this Thank you  - @jQueeny

Answer (score 1):

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const app = express();
const port = 3000;


router.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("test 1");
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    next(); 
});

router.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("test 2");
    console.log(req.originalUrl);

});

app.use("/test", router);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Running on port", port);
});
```

This discrepancy occurs because `router.get("/test",...)` is actually looking for a path of `/test/test` due to the way routers are nested and paths are interpreted in Express.js. Since such a path is not defined in your setup, the request to /test is handled by the routes mounted at `/test` and defined as `/` within the router, not the ones looking for `/test` within the router.

Answer (score 0):

The output you're seeing is correct based on the current implementation.

Currently you have the following top level routes defined in your instance:

localhost:3000/test
localhost: 3000/test/test

Under the `/test` route you've setup two functions / middleware:

#1 - first /
#2 - second /

Under the `/test/test` route you currently have another two functions / middleware setup:

#1 - test 1
#2 - test 2

Perhaps restructuring the code (shown below) can help visualize the order in which the request will be handled based on the route:

```
router.get("/test",(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log("test 1");
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    next()
})

router.get("/test",(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log("test 2");
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    next()
})

router.get("/",(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log("first /");
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    next()
})

router.get("/",(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log("second /");
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    next()
})
```